# WPF: Remove hover effect after triggering TouchLeave event

Tags: wpf

Is there way to disable IsMouseOver on elements after triggering TouchLeave?
So, problem: when you touchclick button (or another element) mouse position set to touch position and it sets IsMouseOver to true until next touchclick
Tried set cursor position to 0,0, but if user use mouse with touch it seems like "what the hell is going on"
Tried set cursor to position 0,0 and after mousemove restoring previous position but it not works because mouse can be outside the app and mousemove don't triggering until mouse outside the app
Tried set cursor to inside app position but IsMouseHover didn't disappear 

Please feel free to ask any addintional info

Comment: Did you implement the MouseOver-Effect in XAML? Show some code pls so we can understand what you are trying to do. I don't get what you actually try to do.

Comment: Yeah I implemented mouseover effect and it works perfect. I just trying to remove mouseover effect after touchleate event

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom template for button.